# Add whole S3 images bucket to Amazon Rekognition collection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

In AWS CLI, I can add to a collection only a single image at a time.

Is there any way to add the whole S3 bucket to a collection?

Answer (score 2):

The `IndexFaces()` API call accepts only **one image at a time**, but can index up to 100 faces from that image.

If you wish to add faces from multiple images (eg a whole bucket or folder), you would need to call `IndexFaces()` **multiple times** (once per image). This would involve a call to Amazon S3 to list the files, then a loop to call `IndexFaces()`.

It would be relatively simple in a scripting language like Python.